# rounding up with python

Tags: python, django, rounding

I've read the following pages:

[python decimals - rounding to nearest whole dollar (no cents) - with ROUND_HALF_UP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935661/python-decimals-rounding-to-nearest-whole-dollar-no-cents-with-round-half)

http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html

I have the following code:

```
total_num = Decimal(str(total/10))
total_num.quantize(Decimal('1'), rounding=ROUND_UP)
```

But its always rounding down? So if I have 221, I want it to return 23. Right now I'm getting 22. Is there something I'm misunderstanding regarding this?

**[EDIT]**

I changed it to the following: `total_num = int(math.ceil(float(total)/10))`

I needed an `int` to continue with the `for` loop that has a `range`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you use math.ceil? It will do the necessary thing if you are using a float division. Currently you are doing an integer division.

Comment: Also add that the OP uses a float value to ensure its doing float division

Answer (score 3):

`total` is an integer. As such, `/` is doing integer division. Either divide by `10.` (and hope that precision limits don't bite you in the ***), or do your math in `Decimal` with an appropriate context.